# Grace note in Bar 20 of Chopin's Op. 10 No. 3

Tags: piano, notation, ornaments, chopin

What is the correct interpretation of the ornament in bar 20 of Chopin's Etude Op. 10 No. 3 — that is, the final full bar below:

[image: Bar 20]

The recordings I've heard generally repeat the G# but not all of them do — which is correct; is there any ambiguity at all?

Answer (score 2):

In the Henle Urtext edition there is no tie on G# and nothing is said about it in the commentary. This suggests that there is no ambiguity: it should be repeated. Also the grace notes should be in the following bar which may or may not affect your interpretation. And the slur should start on the half note G#, there is no slur on the preceding 16th notes. But there should be a slur B-C# in the previous bar. Etc. :p